# How to group only the children of an element in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

Please note that I need to use XSL version 1.0 only.
My XML is something like:

```
<Person>
    <Tp>
        <Tl acc="999" />
        <Tl acc="999" />
        <Tl acc="777" />
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Tl acc="999" />
        <Tl acc="888" />
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Tl acc="999" />
        <Tl acc="888" />
        <Tl acc="888" />
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Tl acc="666" />
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Tl acc="555" />
        <Tl acc="333" />
        <Tl acc="555" />
        <Tl acc="555" />
    </Tp>
</Person>
```

Expected output is:

```
<Person>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>999</Acc>
        <Acc>777</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>999</Acc>
        <Acc>888</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>999</Acc>
        <Acc>888</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>666</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>

        <Acc>555</Acc>
        <Acc>333</Acc>
    </Tp>
</Person>
```

I have tried the Muenchian grouping. But the problem is that this technique identifies the unique entries in the entire document i.e. all the `<Tl>` tags in the document. However, I would like to identify the unique entries within the specific `<Tp>` tag only. I have already tried the below:

and the for each is as below

The above XSL returns the following:

```
<Person>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>999</Acc>
        <Acc>777</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>888</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>
        <Acc>666</Acc>
    </Tp>
    <Tp>

        <Acc>555</Acc>
        <Acc>333</Acc>
    </Tp>
</Person>
```

The 999 and 888 from second and third `<Tp>` are one.

**Edit: Added the complete XSL**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">


        <xsl:key use="@acc" name="myaccounts" match="Tl"></xsl:key>


        <xsl:template match="/">
            <Person>
                <xsl:for-each select="Person/Tp">
                    <Tp>
                        <xsl:for-each
                            select="Tl[generate-id() = generate-id(key('myaccounts', @acc)[1])]">
                                <Tl>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@acc"></xsl:value-of>
                                </Tl>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Tp>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Person>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please show the XSLT you have currently tried, even if it doesn't produce the output you require. Muenchian grouping is the way to go, so your current attempt might not be that far off. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC, added the XSL. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not far off, but the issue is you want to take into account of the `Tp` elements. As the `Tp` elements themselves have no attribute, or child element, to uniquely identify them, you can make use of the `generate-id()` function instead, and use that in the key

```
<xsl:key name="Tl" match="Tl" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @acc)" />
```

So, you are grouping by `Tp` element and by `@acc` element. Note the use of the pipe `|` is arbitrary. It just needs to be any character that does not occur in the `@acc` attribute.

Then, assuming you are positioned on a `Tp` element, you select the distint `Tl` elements like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Tl[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Tl', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @acc))[1])]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="Tl" match="Tl" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @acc)" />

    <xsl:template match="Tp">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Tl[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Tl', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @acc))[1])]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the Identity Template to copy existing elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a life saver.